# UITableView select event not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to make each cell in my UITableView clickable. I'm using storyboards, both UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource are in ViewController.h and the table displays data correctly. To my ViewController.m I've added such code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    long selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"touch on row %ld", selectedRow);
}
```

The problem is that when I click on any cell this action isn't invoked. Maybe I should add some Connection to cell prototype?

Comment: have you set the tableview delegate to self?

Comment: @Wraithseekerr Thank you a lot! I've set the datasource, but not the delegate. That's my first iOS app, didn't knew that. I have background on Windows Phone and didn't thought that I should manually set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `UITableView` delegate to self and it should work. You might have forgotten to have set it in your storyboard and thus you you can do it using code instead.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can try to set a break point to see whether it's getting called.
2. Check whether `userInteractionEnabled` is enabled
3. Check whether there are something covering on top of your `UITableViewCell` that prevents the touch passing to your `UITableViewCell`

Comment: I've tried debugging and I see that it's not called. Both table and cell have enabled interaction. And there is nothing above them.

Comment: I assumed you have already known how to set up the `UITableView` and those are common mistakes. Did not aware that your setup is not completed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was enabling setEditing: on tableview which cause didSelectRowAtIndexPath: not being call.
If you want editing mode and also selection enable you can easily set both:

```
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:NO];
self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```